# Function for subtracting a value from one cell also subtracts that value from another cell

Tags: excel, subtraction

Example:

Credit Debt = 200

Bank = 500

Subtract 100 from Credit Debt will also subtract 100 from Bank

Credit Debt = 200 - 100

Bank = 400

Please let me know if this is possible.
Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Place the credit amount in **A1** and the bank amount in **A2**.
Place the value to be subtracted in **A3**.

Then in **B1** enter:

```
=A1-A3
```

for the reduced credit and in **B2** enter:

```
=A2-A3
```

for the reduced bank amount.

Comment: Your solution helped me find another solution. I used a blank cell, turned the text white, and added the value. I used the blank cell and subtracted it from the Bank and Credit Debt cells.

Answer (score 0):

You could add a cell that contains the cash in bank and then define formula for the total amount of money in the Bank.

For example, if Credit cell is `A1` and new Cash cell is `A2` then the formula for Bank is `=A1+A2`